# Integer optimization method

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

Suppose I have to maximize 
$f(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n{(2-i)}.$ Which of these two methods is correct (generally, not only for this example)?

1) Since $f(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n{(2-i)}=\displaystyle\frac{(4-n)(n+1)}{2}.$ Then I assume that $x=n$ is continuous and solve:

$g(x)=\displaystyle\frac{(4-x)(x+1)}{2}$ and its maximum is attained at $x=1.5$ then I simply need to check the values of $f(n)$ for $n=1$ and $n=2.$

2) Since I assume $x$ is continuous then the original equation must be 
$f(x)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}(2-t)dt=\displaystyle\frac{(4-x)x}{2}$and its maximum is attained at $x=2$ therefore the maximum of the original problem is $n=2.$.

Comment: As soon as $n>2$ you're adding negative numbers. There's no need for equation solving.

Comment: Advice: before selecting any method for your problem. First have a look at your objective function and imagine what is going on there.. As in this example you may be puting more effort than it is necessary..

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Method 1 is not correct, what if $g(x)=-26x^3+81x^2-61x+6$, maximum is in $f(1.5)=9$ yet integer maximum is in $f(0)=6$ not in $f(1)=f(2)=0$...

Comment: @zwim, your $g(x)$ is not concave, but the OP's $g(x)$ is concave, in which case the integer maximizer is either $\lfloor x^*\rfloor$ or $\lceil x^* \rceil$, where $x^*$ is the continuous maximizer.

Comment: Sure this was on purpose, we'll have to ask @Quema if "you though about this justification or not ?"

Comment: Thanks, if $f(n)$ is concave (in the continuous case) then method 1 is correct? Or shall I use method 2. My doubt is when I relax the problem and assume the variable to be continuous if I can use the summation result or change the original problem with an integral.